# Show VB6 forms when click a link in html page of webbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, vb6, webbrowser-control

I am working with VB6 WebBrowser, Here i need to open a vb6 form when user click any particular link of `WebBrowser`'s link like

**In HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<a href="--show vb6 form--">Click To show VB6 Form2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I do't have any idea how to do it. I thought sometime it can be done a third text file like when the link clicked will write a cod like `002` in a text file.

And the in vb form a Timer will check once a second the file, when timer detect the file contains `002` it will show the form.

Can be do this by this method? or anything else shorter i can except?

Comment: did you wrote the HTML page? Can you modify the markup to add some information to the `a` Tag ?

Comment: yes i wright it. I can change it

Comment: added example with a custom `data-attribute`, check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a better naming scheme like:

```
<a href="#vb-showform2">Click To show VB6 Form2</a>
<a href="#vb-waffles">Waffles</a>
```

Then intercept link clicks via the `BeforeNavigate2` event, look at the url and if it matches `#vb-*` run your code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowserCtrl_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    '// get #vb-XXX command from url
    Dim pos As Long: pos = InStrRev(URL, "#vb-")

    If pos Then
        Cancel = True '// stop default navigation

        URL = Mid$(URL, pos + 4)

        Select Case LCase$(URL)
            Case "showform2": Form2.Show
            '...
            Case "waffles":   MsgBox "Waffles."
            Case Else:        MsgBox "Unknown Command " & URL
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. its worked for me. its helped me

Answer (score 4):

Instead of putting the form name inside the `href` attribute, I believe a better method would be to set a **your own** `data attribute` and use that, it seems to me a much cleaner way to do such a task.

In my example, inside the `href` tag i'm using the classic `void(0)` to prevent the link navigation, otherwise your external link to VB forms could break the browser history with unexpected results.

To use the `WebBrowser` control, You should have already added in your VB project a reference to the `Microsoft Internet Controls`, what you need next is to add a reference to the `Microsoft HTML Library`, the type library contained inside the `mshtml.tlb` file.

Assuming your `WebBrowser` control is called "WebBrowser1", and you have three additional forms called "Form1", "Form2" and "Form3", in the form where you placed the `WebBrowser` control put this piece of code:

```
Private HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

' Create a Web Page  to test the navigation '
' You can skip this phase after your test are successfully executed '
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim HTML As String
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
    HTML = "<html>"
    HTML = HTML & "<title>Open a VB Form from a Link</title>"
    HTML = HTML & "<body>"
    HTML = HTML & "<a data-vb='Form1' href='javascript:void(0)'>Click To show Form1</a>"
    HTML = HTML & "</br>"
    HTML = HTML & "<a data-vb='Form2' href='javascript:void(0)'>Click To show Form2</a>"
    HTML = HTML & "</br>"
    HTML = HTML & "<a data-vb='Form3' href='javascript:void(0)'>Click To show Form3</a>"
    HTML = HTML & "</br>"
    HTML = HTML & "</body>"
    HTML = HTML & "</html>"
    WebBrowser1.Document.Write HTML
End Sub

' This will load and show the form specified in the data-vb attribute of the link '
Private Sub WebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim frm As Form, FormName as String
    If Not (WebBrowser1.Document Is Nothing) Then
        Set HTMLdoc = WebBrowser1.Document
        FormName = vbNullString & HTMLdoc.activeElement.getAttribute("data-vb")
        If Not FormName = vbNullString Then    
            Set frm = Forms.Add(FormName)
            frm.Show
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

An additional note:

You can get the content of the clicked link in following way:

```
HTMLdoc.activeElement.toString
```

Obviously, for all links in my test page, the result will be:

`javascript:void(0)` which is the same as the *URL* parameter of the BeforeNavigate event.

Another useful information which you can get from the `HTMLDocument` and wouldn't be available in the `BeforeNavigate` event is, for example:

```
HTMLdoc.activeElement.outerHTML
```

the result will be:

```
<A href="javascript:void(0)" data-vb="Form2">Click To show Form2</A>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a button instead of a link, add the button to the document and a bit of javascript:

```
<input type="button" id="MyButton1_id" style="cursor: pointer" name=MyButton1 value="Show It!">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub MyButton1_OnClick()
   location.href = "event:button1_show"
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Then in the `BeforeNavigate2` event:

```
Public Sub webBrowser_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

  Select Case LCase$(URL)
    Case "event:button1_show"
      Cancel = True
      Form2.Show
    Case "event:other_stuff"
      'other stuff to do, etc
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: good catch, agree that displaying a button and using a bit of JavaScript would be correct way to execute actions outside the HTML page. Upvoting, but your `event:button1_show` is hurting my eyes... :)

Comment: @deblocker, yup, not pretty.  I simply pasted in what's the required convention 'round here (it's an event and identify the event).  Cancel the navigation (`Cancel = True`) and it's simply an identifying string - one can just use their own preferred flavor lollipops for that.  :-)